# Variable not declared in this scope c++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and have this program which takes an amount of money and computes the maximum number of 5 dollar bills allowed and assigns it to `numFives`. The leftover money will be in ones and should be assigned to `numOnes`. This all assumes that the provided money is 19.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int amountToChange = 0;
   int numFives = 0;
   int numOnes  = 0;

   amountToChange = 19; 
   numFives = amountToChange / 5; 

   numOnes = amountToChange - (numFives * 5); //error occurs here

   return 0;
}
```

I am assuming my logic is correct here, but whenever I run the code I get this error:

```
error: ‘numFives’ was not declared in this scope
```

It seems to be that the variable is initialized properly and I just do not see any issues with the code.

Comment: Looks correct to me - is this the code that gives the error?

Comment: Just FYI, "defined" and "declared" don't mean the same thing. But your code should compile.

Comment: @Barry It is precisely. I feel like something else has to be wrong here, I just needed an extra set of eyes to make sure I am not messing this up because it looks fine to me.

Comment: Is this all of the code?  Only thing I can think of is maybe a different instance of `numFives` orphaned somewhere else.

Comment: What is your compiler? Compiles fine on `clang`.

Comment: What kind of system are you on? What editor did you use to type in your program?

Comment: https://ideone.com/JyUTWn (C++14) compiled fine
https://ideone.com/6slVeD (C++03) compiled fine

Comment: @RyanGray -  If you're using Visual Studio, stop posting Intellisense errors.  They are *not* compiler errors as Intellisense is *not* a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic *is* correct and so is the code you've posted.

So, unless you've found a serious bug in your compiler, my suggestion is that the code you've posted is *not* the code causing that error.

My advice is to go back to the code and recheck that you have spelt `numFives` *exactly* the same way each time. The fact that it only complains about the variable the *second* time you try to use it seems to indicate a misspelt variant on the line you mark as the error.

If necessary, delete that line and retype it.

Another possibility is that you've cut and pasted the code from an application that allows strange characters, something I've seen with "smart" quotes amongst other things:

```
puts (“won't work”);
puts ("will  work");
```

You can generally find out if that's the case by doing a hex dump of your program such as with the Linux `od` program:

```
$ echo "    puts (“won't work”);" | od -xc
0000000    2020    2020    7570    7374    2820    80e2    779c    6e6f
                          p   u   t   s       ( 342 200 234   w   o   n
0000020    7427    7720    726f    e26b    9d80    3b29    000a
          '   t       w   o   r   k 342 200 235   )   ;  \n
0000035
```

and looking for stuff that doesn't belong. In your case, that would be something around the final `numFives` occurrence.

---

As an aside, you could also look into using:

```
numOnes = amountToChange % 5;
```

to work out the remainder. It will "fix" your problem in the sense that the error should hopefully disappear but I'd work out the root cause before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio, you are posting an error given by the `Intellisense` tool that is responsible for C++ source code tag management.

Intellisense is *not* a compiler -- if you see that your code is correct, but Intellisense gives an error, that doesn't mean your code is wrong.